# how to get data in class extending sherlockfragmentactivity and distribute in different fragments?

Tags: android, wcf, android-fragments, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock-map

I want to receive data from WCF web service in class extending SherlockFragmentActivity and distribute the received data in three viewPager tabs? what is the best way to do this? or i have to call web service in each of the fragment?

Thank you in advance